# Notebook's TaggingRules inherit too much

Tags: bugs, front-end, options, inheritance

**Bug introduced in V10.4 or earlier and persisting through V12.0**

> [CASE:3852725] was created
>
> [...] I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. [...]

---

This small helper function will show us `TaggingRules` written explicitly to the notebook. (Because `Options/CurrentValue` show values merged from `$FrontEnd/$FrontEndSession` too)

```
nbTR[] :=  TaggingRules /. List @@ Rest @ NotebookGet @ EvaluationNotebook[]
```

Here is the story:

- create a new notebook and evaluate:

  ```
  CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "a"}] = 1;
  ```
- now we can check that notebook's `TaggingRules` are nicely merged even though they are not written explicitly:

  ```
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "a"}]
  nbTR[]
  ```

  > 1
  >
  > TaggingRules
- ***Pay attention now!*** Let's use example from documentation: [**TaggingRules / Applications**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TaggingRules.html)

  So we want to have some tagging rules local to the notebook:

  ```
  CurrentValue[
    EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "InputFieldState"}
  ] = "initial string";
  ```
- And let's check:

  ```
   CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "InputFieldState"}]
  ```

  > "initial string"

  but

  ```
  nbTR[]
  ```

  > {......., "a" -> 1 (*??!!*), "InputFieldState" -> "initial string"}

So the bottom line is, if the notebook doesn't contain `TaggingRules` explicitly then it will inherit all you have in `$FrontEnd`/`$FrontEndSession`!

And this is a problem because:

- I didn't modify `"a"'s` value on a notebook level but it is now localized here and won't inherit external changes:

  ```
  CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "a"}] = 22;
      CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "a"}]
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "a"}]
  ```

  > 22
  >
  > 1 (*!!!*)
- Not to mention that you write to file possibly private data without notice.

I consider this a serious flaw. Any suggested prevention measures?

Comment: How do you come across these things? ti is always interesting to see your reports, something that I can't imagine ever stumbling upon...

Comment: @user6014 I'm trying to create something more than just .m .tr based packages :) I found this problem because I'm doing something like: [**131158**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131158/5478) but on larger scale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to set empty `Tagging` rules first:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules] = {};

CurrentValue[ EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "InputFieldState"}] = "initial string";
```

Which is fine enough for my purposes but this is ok only if the notebook was just created or you know that there aren't any `TaggingRules`.

---

The problem of course appears when you don't know and you don't want to overwrite them with `{}`. `Options / CurrentValue` (`Absolute` or not) will only tell you what is there with already included `$FrontEnd` values, so to check what is explicitly written you have to call `NotebookGet`, and it doesn't scale well as notebook size grows.

So to check you can run:

```
MemberQ[TaggingRules -> _] @ Rest @ NotebookGet[]
```

---

**p.s**. there is an undocumented syntax for `CurrentValue` so that by using:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "test"}, 2]
```

we say "give me TaggingRules 'test' value and if it doesn't exist, set it to `2` and return `2`. Very convenient. But

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules, {}]
```

doesn't work in this case :)

Comment: You could also set a default for the notebook tagging rules in a style sheet, e.g., `Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], TaggingRules -> {}]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Yep, I've seen your answer, good idea for most cases. For my use case it was easier to just create notebooks with empty rules.