# Inherited TaggingRules misbehaving

Tags: front-end, options, inheritance

Here's an example:

```
CurrentValue[
    $FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "a", "a1"}
] = 22;

CurrentValue[
    EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules
] = {"a" -> {"a1" -> 1, "a2" -> 2}, "b" -> 5}


CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "a", "a1"}]
   (* 1  - ok*)

CurrentValue[
   EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "a", "a1"}
] = Inherited

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules]
```

> ```
> {"b" -> 5}
> ```

So whole `"a"` TaggingRules were dropped.

One could say that maybe it doesn't work with nested rules but will work on the first level of TaggingRules. Well, it does not, `"a" -> 1` set to Inherited will be dropped despite `$FrontEndSession` tagging rules:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules] = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 5};
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules]
    (*{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 5}*)
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "a"}] = 22;
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "a"}] = Inherited;
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules]
    (*{"b" -> 5}*)
```

Am I missing something? How to make it work?

Maybe related: [Notebook's TaggingRules inherit too much](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139017/5478)

> CASE:3893084

Comment: Are you using the new Version 11.1.1, that has all the bug fixes?