# CreateNotebook["Testing"] writes all TaggingRules to the notebook

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, options, testing-and-verification

**Bug introduced in V11.2 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**

> CASE:4072649

---

Some of notebook types generate notebooks with `TaggingRules` for their purposes:

```
Rest @ NotebookGet @ CreateNotebook["SlideShow"]
```

> ```
> Notebook[..., TaggingRules -> {"SlideShow" -> True}, ...]
> ```

#### Problem

But "Testing" notebook gets all you have there:

```
Rest @ NotebookGet @ CreateNotebook["Testing"]
```

[image]

It is not acceptable. The reason is probably that [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [Notebook's TaggingRules inherit too much](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139017/5478) and not keeping it it mind.

#### Obvious fix problem

Using workaround from linked topic, one could try to `nb = CreateDocument[{}, TaggingRules -> {}]` and then convert it `CreateNotebook["Testing", nb]`, but

> CreateNotebook::noconv: Converting ... to type Testing is not supported yet.

#### Question

I have no doubts it is a bug, how to overcome this and create a clean testing notebook programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to realize which TaggingRule testing notebook cares about and overwrite all with this one:

```
nb = CreateNotebook["Testing"];
SetOptions[nb, TaggingRules -> {"$testsRun" -> False}];
Rest @ NotebookGet @ nb
```

---

My final goal was to export a testing notebook without prompting a visible notebook. Unfortunately `CreateNotebook` does not accept options :). So maybe someone will find this code useful:

```
Export[
    pathToFile
  , Notebook[{}
      (*first two options are not related to the problem but are Git firendly :) *)
    , "TrackCellChangeTimes" -> False
    , PrivateNotebookOptions -> {"FileOutlineCache" -> False}
    , TaggingRules ->  {"$testsRun" -> False}
    , StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"MUnit"},"MUnit.nb",CharacterEncoding->"UTF-8"]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: `CreateNotebook` should take options (and for `"Template"` it's happy to use `Visible->False`). Unfortunately the `"Testing"` notebook seems to be all kinds of messed up.

Comment: Turns out that's because it just calls ``MUnit`PaletteNewTestNotebook[]`` which doesn't take options, but which does set the stylesheet to be ``FrontEnd`FileName[{"MUnit"}, "MUnit.nb"]``. The `TaggingRules` are actually just inserted by: ``FrontEndResource["MUnitExpressions", "MUnitStaticToolbar"]``.

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks, I was sure that the documentation is silent about options but it actually allows them. Another bug to the bucket -.-

Comment: Yeah it feels these days like a lot of the front-end development is as rushed as what I do... Hopefully that means it's all going into a new stunning 64 bit FE.