# FindShortestTour causes kernel crash

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization, windows, crash

**I have contacted support, CASE:4075709**
**UPDATE**
I have received reply from wolfram support. They have confirmed that this is indeed a bug. There are lots of sets of data that can cause the Kernel to crash in this situation.

I was trying to solve a complex problem, in which I have to take some random points and calculate the minimum distance for the tour around the points:

```
SeedRandom[100];
FindShortestTour[RandomReal[100, {35, 2}]]
```

This works fine if I run it for only a few times, however, if I use something that calculates this for more than a few times, like the following, I run into trouble.

```
RepeatedTiming[FindShortestTour[RandomReal[100, {35, 2}]], 3]
```

This would run fine for the first time or so, but running it for the second time without restarting the Kernel would cause the Kernel to crash, turning every `In[]` and `Out[]` into `In[*]` and `Out[*]`, erasing every variable assigned, and gives out no result.

Since this stuff crashes, there is no tracing available for my situation. But since `FindShortestTour` works for as many as 10000 points, this shouldn't happen for merely 35 points. Why does my kernel crash?

So I have tried it again and again. The CPU load and memory usage rises during calculation, but not more than 10%. And sometimes the program actually runs. I have been unable to find a way to solve this-reinstalling Mathematica didn't seem to help.

Opening the Kernel directly and running this code would cause the program to exit.

### Update

My solution to this problem is to install an older version of Mathematica, 11.0 works fine on my computer. I suppose there is a better solution for this-as @Kuba has suggested, installing an older version is not really a good way, as it does not solve the problem, but to escape from it.

I am using Mathematica 11.3.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't get any crashes in M10, M11.1 or M11.3 on OSX. What Mathematica version and OS are you using? Could you add a SeedRandom[..] call so that it is repeatable?

Comment: @CarlWoll It crashes for almost every random I use. I'm using Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 10

Comment: It is the nature of crashes that whether they are actually triggered may depend on effectively random things, such as the memory contents.  Just because many people can't trigger the crash does not mean that there isn't a serious bug present.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still unable to reproduce the crash on MMA 11.2 Win7-64, even when using your `SeedRandom` value. You can report it to Wolfram Support (they may have more insight), but I am not sure that we can help you further.

Comment: I reproduce the crash with version 11.3 on Windows 7 x64 when running `RepeatedTiming[FindShortestTour[RandomReal[100, {35, 2}]], 3]` two times in a fresh kernel (`SeedRandom` isn't necessary). Please report this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: I also reproduce the crash by running `Do[Do[FindShortestTour[RandomReal[100, {35, 2}]], 100], 2]` in a fresh kernel.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, that is exactly what I encountered, I will send the report right away

Comment: Yes, kernel crashes for me in both 11.2 and 11.3  Win7 64.

Comment: @t-smart Once you reported the issue and you get a case number from Wolfram, would you consider updating your question and include a bug header like [Kuba did here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173855/187)? Also, add the `[bugs]` tag. I think 3 confirmed crashes is enough.