# LocalSymbol remains unevaluated in autoload package?

Tags: localsymbol

I am using `LocalSymbol` to store some database credentials. I put a statement like this in a user-level autoload package:

```
$PostgresCredentials = LocalSymbol @ "DefaultPostgres";
```

This returns unevaluated when this package is autoloaded (i.e. it evaluates to `LocalSymbol @ "DefaultPostgres"`). `Evaluate` does not fix the issue.

If I reload the package manually after my session has started, then `$PostgresCredentials` correctly pulls the `LocalSymbol`. And of course if I define it with `SetDelayed` it will work.

I am just wondering what the problem is. Is it possible to access a `LocalSymbol` at the autoload stage?

Comment: I have not tried to reproduce this problem, but I know that there are several things that do not work during kernel initialization.  The typical symptoms tend to be different from what you describe though.  Take a look at this question and the links within: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132212/12

Comment: My point is that there are many limitations during initialization, and you may be forced to roll your own [persistent storage](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130534/12) implementation. One way is to write/read an `.m` file to/from `$UserBaseDirectory/ApplicationData/YourPackageName`.  Use `Put`/`Get` to do this, not `Export`/`Import`.  `Export`/`Import` does not work during initiailzation. A nice way is to just put an association with string keys into that `.m` file.

Comment: Another thing: I would be cautious with LocalSymbol if you plan to distribute your package. [`LocalSymbol` has trouble with paths that contain spaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124570/12).  Windows encourages usernames with spaces, which means that LocalSymbol's default storage location will often have spaces on Windows ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I did intend to use it for packages so I will avoid this can of worms. I'll use your `Get` suggestion instead.